# Possible Data caching issue with flex datagrid

Tags: java, apache-flex, caching, actionscript, blazeds

I have an application in which there are 5 tabs. Each tab has a datagrid. The dataprovider to the datagrid in 1st tab is the common dataprovider to datagrids in other tabs. data in each of the tab varies based on status except for the 1st tab where i display all the data. Now the data for main tab is refreshed every minute using a timer to fetch new data from the backend[Use Blazeds to interact with server side code i.e Java].

After i perform any operation on any of the row in any of the tab other than the 1st one i need to delete the row from that datagrid. I am able to do that by removing the entry from the dataprovider but as soon as i go back to the main tab and return to the tab where i had done the operation i find the deleted entry back. The point to note here is that the entry is not there in the main tab nor it is in the tab where i performed the operation but as soon as i navigate between the tabs it is shown in the UI. But if i do a refresh using F5 it behaves normally.

I was just wondering whether this issue is due to the data caching on the client side and if so what can be a solution to this ?

Comment: Provide some code. Unless all the DataGrids use the same dataProvider, there is no reason to expect that deleting an item from one grid (and dataProvider) that all others will update.  If you're data needs to be updated every minute, you should consider a server that can perform a data push to the client, such as GaniteDS or LiveCycle.

Answer (score 1):

After you delete the object from the arrayCollection / data - run a `collectionName.refresh()` on it.

That said, my best guess is that I think you're running into a situation where you're updating a pointer or copy ref rather than the actual data and it's getting reset into that pointer with binding or similar.

If you add a binding listener / change watcher on the object that is bound to the datagrid that traces to console when it gets a `CHANGE` event, I bet you get a surprise!

(btw, this is how to debug this type of issue quickly).

Comment: This is a very old issue, not valid any more. The implementation has changed and the issue no longer exists. Anyway thanks for your input Nate :). I will definately keep this in mind when i work on ArrayCollection next time.

Comment: I think I answered another of your questions then took a look if you had anymore that hadn't been answered.  That's all.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From your situation its very hard to say without looking at your code. I do agree with the comments passed by the Flextras.

> once you deleted it does not show in the tab and when you navigate
>   to Main tab  it does not either show
>   there and only when you come back
>   again  to the the same tab it does not
>   get reflected.

It seems there could be an issue with your DB Queries [May be]. Why don't you recheck with your queries where once the delete operation is performed, does the DB tables get reflected or not.

**If the above turns out to be false, then get back to the next step.**

- What does trace() of the dataprovider
  give you. I mean what does it
  contain? Try this on the select event
  of the tab.
- Your dataprovider May be holding previous values, though the item from
  the grid being deleted is not reflecting the dataprovider. Did you 
  try to refresh the datagrid or why don't you call invalidateProperties()
  method to check.
- Once again a some piece of code tabs 
  could help you and us a lot of time in giving a correct riposte to the question.